# Spark Streaming memory usage doubts

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to figure out the memory used by executors for a Spark Streaming job. For data I am using the rest endpoint for Spark AllExecutors
and just summing up the metrics `totalDuration * spark.executor.memory` for every executor and then emitting the final sum as the memory usage.

But this is coming out to be very small for application which ran whole day , is something wrong with the logic.Also I am using dynamic allocation and executorIdleTimeout is 5 seconds.

Also I am also assuming that if some executor was removed for due to idle timeout and then was allocated to some other task then its totalDuration will be increased by the amount of time took by the executor to execute this new task.

But what is unusual is that as the duration for execution of increases the memory usage metrics is decreasing.